# INotifyPropertyChanged в объекте класса не изменяет интерфейс

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня класс, который отвечает за распаковку диапозонов IP-адресов. И при выборе файла для его работы он сохраняет в себе свойство с путем файла. А вот его это свойство привязано в View части.

В свою очередь все конторолирует ViewModel, в которой и создается экземпляр класса IPParser, суть которого выше.

**xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ipParser.Filepath}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel() - конструктор
{
    IPParser = new IPParser();
}

public ICommand OpenFileForParseIPRangesCommand { get; } - (здесь по нажатию кнопки вызывается метод из объекта)
private void OnOpenFileForParseIPRangesCommandExecuted(object p)
{
    IPParser.Load();
}
```

**IPParser class**

```
public class IPParser : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
        private string _Filepath;
        public string Filepath
        {
            get { return _Filepath; }
            set
            {
                _Filepath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool Load()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = ".txt|*.txt",
            };

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == false) return false;

            Filepath = ofd.FileName;
            return true;
        }
}
```

ViewModel подключена, если биндить к ее свойствам, то все изменяется.
А при изменении IPParser.Filepath не изменяется значение в 
Не пойму, в чем причина. Отладкой узнал, что значение изменяется в объекте, PropertyName тоже подается верный - "Filepath"

**UPD**
объявление самой модели во ViewModel

```
        #region Models
        SessionController SessionController;
        public Scaner Scaner;
        public IPParser ipParser;
        #endregion
```

Comment: `ipParser` - это что? И как часто делается `ipParser = new IPParser();`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ написал ведь, что в конструкторе вызывается. Он лишь один раз выполняется, становясь доступным во всей вью модели. А при нажатии на кнопку, вызывается уже метод этого объекта. Согласен, неверно уточнил в вопросе

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил вопрос

Comment: Вы мне так и не сказали что такое `ipParser`, где этот объект у вас в коде? Я вижу его инициализацию, ок, а сам объект где?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Его класс подписан как "IPParser Class" выше. 
Сам объект хранится во ViewModel самым обычным образом

        #region Models
        SessionController SessionController;
        public Scaner Scaner;
        public IPParser IPParser;
        #endregion

А инициализируется лишь в конструкторе(в вопросе написал)

буду благодарен, если поможете. Во всех примерах так сделано, а у меня не работает

Comment: Ну почему я у вас все вытягиваю клешнями я не пойму, трудно дать этот участок кода? `самым обычным образом` - каким?!

Comment: Вновь дописал в вопрос

Comment: Обновили свой коммент, вижу, `IPParser IPParser;`. Привязка в WPF доступна только к **публичным свойствам**, ваш этот "обычный образ" является "свойством"?

Comment: Большое спасибо, объект хранился в виде поля

Comment: На будущее, пожалуйста, если просят, то не комментариями поясняйте, а давайте то, что просят, кодом. А еще лучше, сразу в вопросе, от самого значения, до всей логики с ним прикладывайте, а не сокращайте до двух непонятных строк... Как видите, я вам решение уже 20 мин назад мог дать, а потратил в итоге их на "обычным образом"...